# Displaying Nested ManyToMany Relation

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having nested many to many relation in my models.py and I've got the display partially working. I have 2 questions:

- Is there a way to simplify the presentation, e.g. by inlineformset?
- How to I access nested context variables in the template form (see line {% for objective in selected_objectives %}  )?

Please let me know if there is a way to make my question more clear

**models.py**

```
class Process(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
desc = models.TextField('process description', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Objective(models.Model):
    process = models.ManyToManyField(Process, verbose_name="related processes", blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField('objective description', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Risk(models.Model):
    objective = models.ManyToManyField(Objective, verbose_name="related objectives", blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    desc = models.TextField('risk description', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
    @login_required
def detailed_list(request): 
    #context = RequestContext(request)
    obj = []
    ri = []

all_processes = Process.objects.order_by('id') #[:1]
for p_index,p in enumerate(all_processes):
    obj.append(p.objective_set.all()) #appending objectives for each process
    for o_index,o in enumerate(obj[p_index]):
        ri.append(o.risk_set.all().values()) #appending risks for each objective


context = {'all_processes': all_processes,
           'selected_objectives': obj,
           'selected_risks': ri
           }

return render(request, 'repository/detailed.html', context)
```

**template detailed.html**

```
<p><a href="{% url 'repository:process_create' %}">Create new Process</a>

</p>
{% if all_processes %}
No: {{ all_processes|length }}
    <ul>
    {% for process in all_processes %}



         <li><a href="{% url 'repository:process' process.id%}">{{ process.title }}</a> {{ forloop.counter0 }}</li>
        <ul>
        {% if selected_objectives %}

            {% for objective in selected_objectives %}
<!-- see here -->               <li><a href="{% url 'repository:objective' %}">{{ objective.title }}</a> {{ forloop.counter0 }} - {{ objective.desc }}</li>

            {% endfor %}

        {% else %}
        <p>No objectives are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>

{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
    <p>No processes are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is just pass the Process object as the context to your template

```
context = {'all_processes': all_processes}
```

and in you template :

```
<p><a href="{% url 'repository:process_create' %}">Create new Process</a>

</p>
{% if all_processes %}
No: {{ all_processes|length }}
    <ul>
        {% for process in all_processes %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'repository:process' process.id%}">{{ process.title }}</a> {{ forloop.counter0 }}</li>
            <ul>
            {% if all_processes.objective_set.all %}
                {% for objective in all_processes.objective_set.all %}
                       <li><a href="{% url 'repository:objective' %}">{{ objective.title }}</a> {{ forloop.counter0 }} - {{ objective.desc }}
                       </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}    
                <p>No objectives are available.</p>
            {% endif %}
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No processes are available.</p>
{% endif %}

<!-- this is if you want to show risks -->

{% for process in all_processes %}
    {% for objective in all_processes.objective_set.all %}
        {% for risk in objective.risk_set.all %}
            {{ risk.desc }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I hope this is what you were expecting !